# Boot non EFI MS-DOS Windows 7 partition with grub2-gpt

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, grub, uefi

I have the following setup:

- [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) Asus Motherboard
- [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) TABLE and Ubuntu on `/dev/sdb`
- MS-DOS TABLE, Windows 7 and Linux Mint on `/dev/sda`

I try to boot the Windows 7 partitions with grub2 from Ubuntu 11.10.

My Windows "System Reserved" is `/dev/sda3`.

The [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) windows entry is (standard):

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)" --class windows --class os {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntfs
        set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 644C5AC04C5A8CA4
        chainloader +1
}
```

[Parted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Parted) output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  296MB   296MB   primary   ext2
 2      296MB   423GB   423GB   extended
 5      296MB   20.3GB  20.0GB  logical   ext4
 6      20.3GB  363GB   342GB   logical   ext4
 7      363GB   423GB   60.1GB  logical   ntfs
 3      423GB   423GB   105MB   primary   ntfs         boot
 4      423GB   500GB   77.2GB  primary   ntfs


Disk /dev/sdb: 1500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      17.4kB  20.0MB  20.0MB  fat16                 boot
 2      20.0MB  50.9GB  50.9GB  ext4
 4      50.9GB  1103GB  1052GB  btrfs
 5      1103GB  1156GB  52.7GB  ext4
 6      1156GB  1233GB  77.2GB  ntfs
 7      1233GB  1233GB  105MB   ntfs
 3      1496GB  1500GB  4271MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

After trying to boot Windows from grub2 I get the message:

> error: invalid EFI file path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You cannot do that.

It should be glaringly obvious that any pre-boot application, such as the boot loader program for an operating system, is tightly coupled to the machine firmware; just as an ordinary applications program is tied to the operating system whose services it employs.  An EFI boot loader program cannot be run on a machine unless that machine provides EFI firmware services.  An old PC/AT style bootstrap loader program cannot be run on a machine unless that machine provides the old PC/AT firmware services.

The `chainloader` verb in GRUB embodies this.  It's not documented, but it does different things depending from how GRUB is hosted — i.e. what machine firmware GRUB is (expecting to be) running on.  On the version of GRUB hosted on old PC/AT systems, it expects to be given a disc block set or a file, and loads and runs (the first sector of) what it is given in the manner of an old PC/AT VBR bootstrap program.  On the EFI-hosted version of GRUB, it expects to be given filenames, and loads and runs the files as ordinary EFI applications.

You have the EFI-hosted version of GRUB.  You've passed `+1` to `chainloader` as the filename, but that simply isn't a valid path to a pre-boot EFI application image file.  GRUB has been unable to construct the *EFI device path* for the image file, because you've given it a syntactically incorrect path.  Hence the error message.

A correct use of `chainloader` in the EFI-hosted GRUB names a file.  For Microsoft Windows NT 6.1, this will be the EFI version of Microsoft's Boot Manager that lives alongside the BCD store on the EFI System Partition:

```
chainload (hd1,gpt1)/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Of course, this will not work for you, because you either didn't install Windows NT 6.1 on this machine — but on some other machine and transferred the hard disc to this one — or didn't install the EFI-bootstrappable version of it, somehow persuading Windows NT 6.1 to run the non-EFI version of its installation utility on your EFI machine.  How do I know?  Because [Microsoft wouldn't have let you install it to a non-EFI-partitioned hard disc on an EFI machine](https://superuser.com/a/373457/38062) as you have done, and because you have both a proper *EFI System Partition* (the FAT partition on your second hard disc) and [its Poor Man's equivalent](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/determining-system-volume.html#Poor) when you would have only needed the former otherwise.

As such, Windows NT 6.1 hasn't been installed with the EFI-hosted version of Microsoft's Boot Manager, the BCD store is in the wrong place, and there will be several other problems — relating to Windows NT expecting one hardware/firmware combination and having been configured with the appropriate drivers and settings for that, and suddenly being bootstrapped on another hardware/firmware combination — in store for you later.